# How to sort numbers in a column based on the entire number, not just the leading digit, in base R?

Tags: r

I have a column of numbers that I want to sort, with the largest number on top and then in descending order. I tried using sort(), but the result places 900 as a larger number than 1000. Basically it's sorting based on the first digit in a number. I don't want that. I want it to sort based on the entire number. Is there a way to do this in base R, without using any library like dplyr.

I've tried multiple ways and lots of googling, and I'm surprised I couldn't find a way to do this. Maybe I'm just going nuts.

SOLUTION: As usual, one more googling attempt after I post and I found a solution. Turns out the class of the column was 'character'. I used as.numeric() to change it to numeric values, then I used sort and it did what I wanted. I'm keeping this post up anyway for anyone in the future that may need it.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please share some data. Add the output of `dput(your_dataframe$that_column)` at the end of your question.

Answer (score 1):

This is the sort of thing that would happen if R was treating the number as a character string, as below.

```
set.seed(1431)
x <- round(runif(10, 0, 25000))
x
# [1] 10799 19832 14455  7657  4517   743  4922 13462 22738
# [10] 19636
xc <- as.character(x)
sort(x, decreasing=TRUE)
# [1] 22738 19832 19636 14455 13462 10799  7657  4922  4517
# [10]   743
sort(xc, decreasing=TRUE)
# [1] "7657"  "743"   "4922"  "4517"  "22738" "19832" "19636"
# [8] "14455" "13462" "10799"
```